# Laravel returns 302 error when trying to send POST request to API route from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

A 302 error is returned when I'm trying to post to API Route, only in the second Post, using the function insereTelefone. When I'm using the Postman, it's working properly, so I think the problem is with Route, but I don't know what. I'm a newbie at the Laravel, so I'm learning how to implement things.

**Here is the controller who calls the POST API:**

```
class IndexClientes extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $request = Request::create('/api/clientes', 'GET');
        $response = Route::dispatch($request);
        $clientes = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);

        return view('index', compact('clientes'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('formulariocliente');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $nome = $request->nome;
        $cpf = $request->cpf;
        $email = $request->email;
        $numerosTelefone = $request->telefone;
        $tiposTelefone = $request->tipoTelefone;

        $request = Request::create('/api/clientes', 'POST', array(
            "nome" => $nome,
            "cpf" => $cpf,
            "email" => $email
        ));

        $responseInicial = Route::dispatch($request);
        $response = json_decode($responseInicial->getContent(), true);
        $status = json_decode($responseInicial->status(), true);

        if ($status !== 200) :
            echo "ERRO";
            die();
        endif;

        $idCliente = $response['id'];

        if (!empty($numerosTelefone)) :
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($numerosTelefone as $numeroTelefone) :
                $tipoTelefone = (int)$tiposTelefone[$i];
                $numeroTelefone = (int)$numeroTelefone;

                if (!empty($tipoTelefone) && !empty($numeroTelefone)) :
                    return self::insereTelefone($idCliente, $tipoTelefone, $numeroTelefone);
                endif;
                $i++;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    }

    public function insereTelefone($idCliente, $tipoTelefone, $numTelefone)
    {
        $array = array(
            "cliente_id" => $idCliente,
            "telefone_tipo_id" => $tipoTelefone,
            "numero" => $tipoTelefone
        );

        $request = Request::create('api/telefones', 'POST', $array);
        $responseInicial = Route::dispatch($request);
        $response = json_decode($responseInicial->getContent(), true);
        $status = json_decode($responseInicial->status(), true);

        return $status;
    }
}
```

**TelefonesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(
        [
            'cliente_id' => 'required',
            'telefone_tipo_id' => 'required',
            'numero' => 'required|max:11'
        ]
    );
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::apiResource('telefones', \App\Http\Controllers\TelefonesController::class);
```

Comment: Please add Route also here,so getting more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i added the routes now

Comment: You didnt post the full code of the store() method fromTelefonesController.php

Answer (score 0):

A 302 response usually means your request is being redirected by laravel.

If you are expecting a json response, you need to set the **Accept: 'application/json'** header along with your request just after the line:

```
$request = Request::create('api/telefones', 'POST', $array ); 
$request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

the first

> Route::dispatch

was redirecting the page, when I'm was trying to run the second Route::dispatch Laravel returns 302, to solve this I'm using the

> app()->handle()

in the function insereTelefone to back to handle the request.

```
public function insereTelefone($idCliente, $tipoTelefone, $numTelefone) {
    

    $array = array(
        "cliente_id"     => $idCliente,
        "telefone_tipo_id"    => $tipoTelefone,
        "numero"    =>  $numTelefone
    
    );

   
    
    $request_telefone = Request::create('api/telefones', 'POST', $array ); 

     
    $responseInicial = app()->handle($request_telefone);
    
    $status = json_decode($responseInicial->status(),true);

    

    return $status;

    

}
```